# Selecting a list of data which can contain values from 2 columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a friend Request table  which holds a friend request data between two users (recipient and sender) and also the friendrequeststatus (ACCEPTED, REJECTED):

[image]

i want to retrieve the friends of the User with id of 1, which include 2, 3, 4 and if possible for them by order of name.

By friend i mean (where a user e.g 1, is either a sender or recipient to another user e.g 2 and the friendrequeststatus has the value of ACCEPETED). By friends i mean all columns where the user e.g 1 whether as a recipient or sender has an accepted friendrequeststatus.

I tried 
`

```
 select request.*
from friendrequest request
where 1 in (request.recipient, request.sender)
```

[image]

Comment: Your table doesn't have the name.  So, your question doesn't have enough information to answer the question you have asked.

Comment: Please define the exact criteria. "Friends" means something to you but not to us. What is the relevance of `time`, which you use in your query but don't describe?

Comment: @GordonLinoff what name and also what information do you require ?

Comment: @eurotrash i have modified my query sir, and also the question, thank you for the correction.

Comment: @Oto-obongEshiett Your question is clearer now; only thing remaining is, can you describe or show what the expected result should look like, based on the sample data you've shown? E.g. a single row with an array of friend ids, or one row per friend?

Comment: @eurotrash one row per friend, like what i did above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup:

```
CREATE TABLE t (id INTEGER, status TEXT, recipient INTEGER, sender INTEGER);

INSERT INTO t
VALUES
(1, 'ACCEPTED', 2, 1),
(2, 'ACCEPTED', 3, 1),
(3, 'ACCEPTED', 1, 4),
(4, 'REJECTED', 5, 1),
(5, 'REJECTED', 1, 5),
(6, 'ACCEPTED', 6, 7),
(7, 'ACCEPTED', 1, 2);
```

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE sender WHEN 1 THEN recipient ELSE sender END AS friends
FROM t
WHERE 1 IN (recipient, sender)
AND status = 'ACCEPTED'
ORDER BY 1
```

Results:

```
| friends |
| ------- |
| 2       |
| 3       |
| 4       |
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sfbFeXCvWkoSagJEipfxSr/0

So firstly I've added some more data to prove only the correct data is used. The query checks recipient/sender for 1, as you did in your query. It also checks the status field for 'ACCEPTED', and then it creates a single column using the value which is not `1` (the CASE statement) to the the friend value form the correct column. It then does a DISTINCT to make sure the same person isn't reported twice (if they're a sender in one record and a recipient in another... if that's even possible). The it orders by that generated column.

Comment: woow, this is great, it works...lemme try it in my code now

Comment: it works sir, but what if i want to go the extra mile . Imagine we have a users table which contains Firstname, lastname and email and  i want to get the Users from the Users Table based on the IDs i have in the friends row . so instead of me just getting a column  of id,the query takes the id's and finds the User in the Users table ?

Comment: @Oto-obongEshiett You'll need to join the users table on the results of this query. See https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sfbFeXCvWkoSagJEipfxSr/1 for an example.